# React Native I want to a style inside nested Text

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I have this Component

```
<Text
   style={tailwind("flex-row justify-between line-through")}
>
    <Text>Guacamole</Text>
    <Text>1/2 Cup</Text>
</Text>
```

[image]

I want the 1/2 Cup to be justify-content: space-between so it can go all the way to the right.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple if you use `<View/>`

You can just have something like that:

```js
<View style={{flexDirection: "row", justifyContent: "space-between"}}>
    <Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'line-through'}}>Guacamole</Text>
    <Text style={{textDecorationLine: 'line-through'}}>1/2 Cup</Text>
</View>
```